# Using AWS CloudHSM to perform a linkable ring signature

Tags: aws, ring-signatures

I'm currently working on an Ethereum project which uses linkable ring signature to sign a message in an anonymous way. Is there a solution to perform this signature in an HSM? I know they're stricly programmable. If you have anything that could help, even tutorials or something, it'd be great. Thank you all!